# AS3 add an image to an "extended" movie clip

Tags: actionscript-3

In AS3 - I use a generic button handler to deal with on-click events on a movie clip object. For the last 4 hours I’ve been trying to add an image to this movie clip (see * * *) object.

The code (I cut and pasted a bit but this all compiles without any errors)

```
btPlay  =   new mcButtonPlay(this,"ClickMe",GameImage); //  GameImage is an BitmapData object
```

---

```
public class mcButtonPlay extends navigationButtonHandler {
    public function mcButtonPlay(Parent:MovieClip,Text:String,GameImage:BitmapData)  {
        super(Text);
        if (GameImage != null) {                
            var ImageBitMap:Bitmap  = new Bitmap(GameImage);
            this.addChild(ImageBitMap); // * * * This doesn’t show
            Parent.addChild(ImageBitMap);   // Works just to test the image
        }                       
    }
}
```

---

```
public class navigationButtonHandler extends MovieClip {
    public function navigationButtonHandler(Text:String)  {
        ChangeButtonTargetText(Text);
        Parent.addChild(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the problem you are having, but you should probably take a look at the AS3 coding conventions here http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions around capitalization of variables and class names.

Comment: I don't think this would work as you can't pass parameters to mcButtonPlay while it extends a class that extends movieclip ... doesn't throw you an error??

Comment: Always capitalize class names and uncapitalize variable names.  Those are strong conventions.

As a matter of style, use the suffix 'Handler' only for event handlers (which are functions).  If you want to signify a MovieClip, add the suffix _mc.

Comment: Adam / Rendall: I appreciate your comments on style and will consider this in future

Eric: No this doesn't throw an error. It works fine but I do believe the issue is somewhere related to the "extend" and "super" code because clearly - just adding a child to a movie clip works fine normally!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it by swapping the super and add child logic around:

```
public class mcButtonPlay extends navigationButtonHandler {
    public function mcButtonPlay(Parent:MovieClip,Text:String,GameImage:BitmapData)  {
        if (GameImage != null) {                
            var ImageBitMap:Bitmap  = new Bitmap(GameImage);
            this.addChild(ImageBitMap); // * * * This doesn’t show
            Parent.addChild(ImageBitMap);   // Works just to test the image
        }                       
        super(Text);
    }
}
```

No idea why though!

Answer (score 0):

```
        this.addChild(ImageBitMap); // * * * This doesn’t show
        Parent.addChild(ImageBitMap);   // Works just to test the image
```

With this code, `ImageBitMap` is being removed from '`this`' and placed in '`Parent`', so you will never see it in '`this`'.

Remove that second line and tell me if it's still working.

Edit:

Are you adding btPlay to the stage or display hierarchy?

eg.

```
btPlay  =   new mcButtonPlay(this,"ClickMe",GameImage); 
this.addChild(btPlay);
```

Comment: I tried it both with and without that second line and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class navigationButtonHandler extends MovieClip {
    public function navigationButtonHandler(Text:String)  {
        ChangeButtonTargetText(Text);
        Parent.addChild(this); //<--------????
    }
}
```

where does `Parent` come from in the above piece of code copied from the question? It would seem the navigationButtonHandler class never gets added to the stage because it doesn't get a `Parent`? So the extended class also is never added to the stage which would be why your image is never shown if you addChild it to your mcButtonPlay class.
Your extended constructor DOES pass a `Parent` parameter but the base class doesn't. That seems weird to me and should not compile. Or are you doing some static things behind the scenes?

And get to work on your capitalization style as mentioned in the comments. It's really a lot easier to read and find errors if you follow common conventions!